# Get current output

Tags: command-line, ssh, console, session

This just crossed my mind.

Let's say that I'm operating a remote machine via SSH and I executed a `make` command to, e.g. build a new kernel for my machine. While I'm logged in that session, I can see in the current console tab what is happening (i.e. the debugging messages).

Then, I close that SSH session (make is still running) and I log in again via SSH (again) and I want to keep seeing those debugging messages in real time (as I had never closed that console tab).

Is this possible?

**PS:** I could still track if `make` is still running, e.g. using `ps axjf | grep make`. But I'm just curious to know if this is possible.

**PS2:** Also, let's say the `make` command, at the end of its execution displays an error message. How can I tell this occurred by the same method described above?

Comment: Take a look at these tutorials about `screen`. (1) http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/a-quick-tutorial-on-screen/ (2) http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use a terminal multiplexer such as `tmux` or `screen`. Essentially you would start your `make` within a `tmux` session, then you can detach from that session and log off. Later, you can log back in and reattach to the session as if nothing had happened.

- [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)
- [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)

Comment: Before `screen` and `tmux`, you'd use a number of tricks, like `nohup make >& make.log`, but these are read-only solutions. Still, if an installation lacks `screen`/`tmux`, they're your only choice.